# Apache POI Setting a cell to be a custom formula

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I've written my own custom formulas in VBA, and now I want to make use of them in my worksheet. I noticed that by doing this, I can set excel preset formulas like SUM for example.

```
c.setCellType(c.CELL_TYPE_FORMULA);
int numIssues = projects.size();
c.setCellFormula("sumMonthlyPerResource(" + numIssues + ")");
```

But it doesn't work for custom formulas. Does apache POI not support the use of custom formulas?

Comment: Which file format is this for - `.xls` or `.xlsx`? (They store formulas differently)

Comment: .xlsxm, macro enabled sheet. But I wouldn't think that would affect it since I can work with it normally, I just can't use custom formulas.